# Port forwarding for VirtualBox + Tor

Tags: forwarding

I am a little confused, maybe someone can help me.

I have configuration like:

- Router [External IP: 91.111.91.111] ->
- PC [Nat IP: 192.168.1.20] ->
- Virtual Machine as a Gateway (Whonix - Tor) [Nat IP 10.0.2.15 + Internal Network 10.152.152.10] internal network is for next Virtual Machine ->
- Virtual Machine Workstation [NAT IP: 10.152.152.50] on this workstation I have installed NoIP DNS: test.noip.com which always shows IP of Tor exit node.

Uff, and now I want to forward port 9000 to that machine. So I set up port forwarding on router and on both Virtual Machines. But it doesn't work :(

I lost something and not sure where I made mistake.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Forward port 9000 from 91.111.91.111 to 192.168.1.20
2. Forward port 9000 from 192.168.1.20  to 10.0.2.15
3. Forward port 9000 from 10.0.2.15 to 10.152.152.10
4. Forward port 9000 from 10.152.152.10 to 10.152.152.50

Do these steps one by one. You should add firewall rules for port forwarding.